# Transiciones Swiper Js no funcionan en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, swiper

estaría agradecido de su ayuda. Estoy desarrollando un sitio web en Wordpress y se me esta presentando el siguiente inconveniente.

Estoy desarrollando el sitio web con Elementor y estoy implementando la libreria Swiper Js para realizar mis slides.

La librería la agrego mediante el plugin Code Snippets con el siguiente código

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','agregar_scripts_styles');
function agregar_scripts_styles(){
    
    wp_register_style('swiper-style','https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css');   
    wp_enqueue_script('swiper','https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js',array('jquery'),'3.6.0',true);   
}
```

Luego en elementor inserto un bloque de código html con el siguiente fragmento

```
 <div class="swiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://automotrizmelipilla.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/1366_2000.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://automotrizmelipilla.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/NAZ_bfbb7f2744d744a9b1ef7db1f228b261.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <img src="https://automotrizmelipilla.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/VLPGALLERYdesk.jpg.ximg_.l_full_m.smart_.jpg">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Add Pagination -->
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
      <!-- Add Navigation -->
      <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
      <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
            effect: 'fade',
        pagination: {
          el: '.swiper-pagination',
          clickable: true,
        },
        navigation: {
          nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
          prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        }
      });
    })
</script>
```

El slide funciona, pero al presionar en las flechas de siguiente y anterior la transición entre cada slide no se visualiza, pero si arrastro con el mouse de un slide hacia el otro la transición si se puede apreciar, pueden ver el resultado en el siguiente enlace https://automotrizmelipilla.com/trayectoria/

Estaría agradecido de su ayuda, ya que no consigo que funcionen las transiciones al presionar en las flechas

Resulta que estoy implementando la libre

Comment: Hola Jonathan, la transición parece que sí que se ejecuta, lo que pasa es que lo hace tan rápido que parece que no lo esté haciendo. Prueba a añadirle, por ejemplo, el parametro "speed: 1000" y debería tardar 1 segundo en hacer la transición. Aquí tienes la lista de todos los parámetros https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api

Comment: A pesar de agregar dicha opción que mensionas sigue sin verse la transición

Comment: Esto es lo que pone en la api del complemento ```speed number 300 
Duration of transition between slides (in ms)``` Comprueba que lo hayas puesto en el sitio correcto.

Comment: Quise salir de una duda, vi el slider desde mi celular y mi notebook y las transiciones si se ven al presionar sobre las flechas, pero solo en mi pc de escritorio no se ven al ser de mayor resolución afectara en algo ?

Comment: verifica si tienes cache activo o prueba desde incognito, yo no veo ningun problema con las transiciones.

Comment: Sii probé borrando el cache y todo el historial, pero aun así no se ven las transiciones, pero solo pasa desde mi computador de escritorio que es de 22" aprox, pero al verla la pagina desde mi notebook las transiciones si se ven, intente con diferentes navegadores y el resultado es el mismo

Comment: proba usar las clases ademas del js onda `<div class="swiper-container swiper-container-fade swiper-container-horizontal"><div class="swiper-wrapper">` ... lista de slides ... `</div><div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets"></div>` y así, podes ver la doc de swiper o armar uno con elementor y copiarle las clases por lo general hay css asociado a las clases para compatibilidad con elementor y wordpress